# Android. Hover action on created bars on custom chart

Tags: android, xamarin, charts, hover

I try to handle "Hover" action in Android. I have to display popup after hover to specific bar on chart. I tried few things, but without any good results.

[After hover to first bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jB1ZV.png)

[After hover to another bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vN3VC.png)

How can I handle that?

Comment: This may be a dumb question, but what is a hover on a phone ?

Comment: Hover in this mean like move over object. In my case move over bar.

Comment: yes I know that, but on a touch screen ?

Comment: Yes. But I am also trying test it on emulator.

Comment: But will your app be used on the emulator or on a real device ?